# Handling special characters in SOLR search for sitecore 9.1

Tags: solr, content-search

For a Dutch company, we implemented Sitecore SOLR search (Sitecore 9.1 and SOLR 7.2.1 ) with a requirement for the user to be able to search words with special Dutch characters for example if the user searches for financiel he should be able to find => financiël. I added the following to the managed schema of the SOLR.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
<analyzer type="index">
    <filter class="**solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory**"/>
 <charFilter class="**solr.MappingCharFilterFactory**" mapping="**mapping-FoldToASCII.txt**"/>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
```

This is my custom index managed schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
 <sitecore>
  <contentSearch>
    <customSolrManagedSchema>
     <commands applyToIndex="sitecore_content_index">
      <add-or-replace-field-type>
        <name>ngram</name>
        <class>solr.TextField</class>
        <positionIncrementGap>100</positionIncrementGap>
        <indexAnalyzer>
          <tokenizer>
            <class>solr.StandardTokenizerFactory</class>
          </tokenizer>
          <filters>
            <class>solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory</class>
          </filters>
          <filters>
            <class>solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory</class>
            <preserveOriginal>false</preserveOriginal>
          </filters>
              <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
          <filters>
            <class>solr.NGramFilterFactory</class>
            <minGramSize>2</minGramSize>
            <minGramSize>35</minGramSize>
          </filters>
       
        </indexAnalyzer>
        <queryAnalyzer>
          <type>query</type>
          <tokenizer>
            <class>solr.StandardTokenizerFactory</class>
          </tokenizer>
          <filters>
            <class>solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory</class>
          </filters>
          <filters>
            <class>solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory</class>
            <preserveOriginal>false</preserveOriginal>
          </filters>
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
        </queryAnalyzer>
      </add-or-replace-field-type>

      <add-dynamic-field>
        <name>*_ngram</name>
        <type>ngram</type>
        <indexed>true</indexed>
        <stored>true</stored>
        <termVectors>true</termVectors>
        <termPositions>true</termPositions>
        <termOffsets>true</termOffsets>
      </add-dynamic-field>
      <add-dynamic-field>
        <name>*_ngramm</name>
        <type>ngram</type>
        <indexed>true</indexed>
        <stored>true</stored>
        <termVectors>true</termVectors>
        <termPositions>true</termPositions>
        <termOffsets>true</termOffsets>
        <multiValued>true</multiValued>
      </add-dynamic-field>
    </commands>
  </customSolrManagedSchema>
</contentSearch>
<pipelines>
  <contentSearch.PopulateSolrSchema>
    <!-- Processor for additional SOLR schema -->
    <processor type="SAA.Feature.Search.Fields.CustomSchemaPopulator, SAA.Feature.Search"               patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.PopulateSolrSchema.PopulateFields, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider']"/>
  </contentSearch.PopulateSolrSchema>
</pipelines>
```

For some reason after adding the following line  `<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>`
to the managed schema as described in some of the [tutorials](https://mrunaldaftari.wordpress.com/2017/02/23/solr-makes-search-with-accented-characters-easy/) , the index was no longer visible in the Sitecore Index manager. If the line is removed the index is visible and some of the fields are indexed, correctly, but some of them are not especially Richtext fields. I am also not sure where is the location of the file described  `<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>` in that line. I also tried [reorganizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162163/solr-accent-removal) the filters in the schema without any success.
Is there any working solution with the following versions of Sitecore 9.1 and SOLR 7.2.1?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: After adding the fields in xml , please restart SOLR service and check the SOLR dashboard -> logging for any errors

Comment: Hi Abhay,
I tried and I found that there was an error about => could not find the mapping-FoldToASCII.txt file, which I added in the index directory, so the error was no longer there, but the problem with special characters is still there.
Thanks for the quick reply !

Comment: Pl add more details to the question , Does sitecore index manager pick up the new Indexes ?

Comment: Yes, it does. The index and the search are working except the part with the special chars.

Comment: I can see this file 'mapping-FoldToASCII.txt' in \server\solr\configsets\sample_techproducts_configs\conf

Answer (score 2):

1.Make sure that you are using preserveOriginal="true" for `solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory` filter

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer  class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter     class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter     class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>        
    <filter     class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>        
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

2. Make sure **mapping-FoldToASCII.txt** is there in the conf folder
3. Before proceeding to testing part, make sure you re-index sample item
4. Then test changes from Solr admin UI
5. Then test it from actual search page

Here is the sample test result -

[image]